# Barcode scanner, reading data from python USB or serial, how to identify what /dev/tty* is using the scanner

Tags: python-2.7, debian, barcode-scanner

I´m trying to reed some data from a barcode scanner in python, using the serial library. My inconvenient is that I´m connecting the barcode scanner to a Virtual Machine where I have a Debian running. I connect the scanner and ir read the data but I cannot identify what /dev/tty* is using, so I can pass as an argument to a server and parse the data it is pacing. In Debian theres is no /dev/ttyACM0 and don´t know why.

Answer to comment:

- HostOS: Windows 10.
- GuestOS: Debian 9 and/or ubuntu 17.04.
- VMtool: workstation 14. All of them 64bit.
- Scanner CINO FUZZYSCAN Model: F680-BSUG.
- Library I was using pyserial, a couple of month a go I was able to use /dev/ttyACM0. Now when I run lsub it gave me this:`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1fbb:3681`
- When run dmesg:

  [ 1026.204937] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbkbd

  [ 1051.955948] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4

  [ 1054.647592] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci

  [ 1055.137077] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1fbb, idProduct=3681

  [ 1055.137083] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0

  [ 1055.137087] usb 1-2: Product: FUZZYSCAN

  [ 1055.137089] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: CINO

  [ 1055.150619] input: CINO FUZZYSCAN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0
  /usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:1FBB:3681.0004/input/input10

  [ 1055.208155] hid-generic 0003:1FBB:3681.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CINO FUZZYSCAN] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input0

So is recognizing the device, but not mapping to /dev/ttyACM0.

Comment: If you write detailed information such as name and version of hostOS / guestOS / VMtool, 32bit / 64bit, manufacturer and model number of scanner, manufacturer and model number of IR chip, it will be easy to get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get It, I haveI finally discovered it, I had the Scanner configured as PS2, instead of USB Com Port Emulation. Once I set up the scanner everything started to work fine.